# Errores en android Studio, no reconoce CardView

Tags: java, android, xml, gradle

[image: Se muestra un error en donde al momento de crear CardView me sale en rojo. Con anterioridad compile las librerias v7 de CardView]

Por favor, desde hace varias horas tengo este error, me aparece en rojo los support de card view, y otra cosa, también me aparece con color amarillo la carpeta .gradle, Gracias.

Comment: tienes instalada la dependencia del cardView en el gradle???

Comment: En efecto, al parecer te falta agregar las dependecias en el gradle, en la parte final de este [artículo](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html?hl=es-419) explican como hacerlo. Espero te sirva.

Comment: Juan David., te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Agrega la [dependencia relacionada a `CardView`](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html?hl=es-419#Dependencies) en tu archivo `build.gradle`, probablemente necesites la dependencia de la bibliotea de diseño (design).

```
dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

}
```

Después sincroniza tu proyecto con los archivos gradle.